# Oracle exception not caught in trigger

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, database-trigger

I'm trying to catch the `ORA-02292 child record found` exception to instead raise a custom exception with my own message.

Here is my simple trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER modifOuSuppressionSucc
BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE ON Succursale
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF DELETING THEN
        UPDATE Projet SET NumSuccursale = NULL
        WHERE NumSuccursale = :OLD.NumSuccursale;
    ELSE
        IF UPDATING AND :NEW.NumSuccursale!=:OLD.NumSuccursale THEN
            UPDATE Projet SET NumSuccursale = :NEW.NumSuccursale
            WHERE NumSuccursale = :OLD.NumSuccursale;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, 'La modification ou la suppression d''une succursale n''est pas possible. Erreur '||SQLCODE||' -ERREUR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

When I try to delete rows in the parent table with the following command, Oracle raise the -02292 exception (which is correct) but my custom exception is not raised with the `WHEN OTHERS THEN` clause.

```
DELETE Succursale  WHERE NumSuccursale=4;
```

I get the standard `ORA-02292 child record found`  message :

```
Erreur commençant à la ligne: 48 de la commande -
DELETE Succursale  WHERE NumSuccursale=4
Rapport d'erreur -
ORA-02292: violation de contrainte (HB691016.SYS_C003806517) d'intégrité - enregistrement fils existant
```

instead of my `-20010` custom error message.

What do I need to change to get it right?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your scenario and I am not able to reproduce it. Can you please share the reproducible example within my [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f8fa2b7922076e8b1d3d6f24de0dd5b9)

Comment: You catch only the exception raised out of your trigger code only, the actual exception thrown here is not related to this trigger code. You should be probably verifying the data integrity associated with the constraints(on SUCCURSALE table) in your trigger and throw an error if it did not meet the conditions.

Comment: Not getting what you are conveying in the last comment- See this [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9944809c95ff393e24af736f2eaa9554). Without Trigger, It is throwing an error, `WITH TRIGGER`, it is not throwing an error. If you are talking about something else then edit db fiddle and share the URL of edited db fiddle

Answer (score 0):

A Trigger is not appropriate for this. If you are bound to have deletes in the parent table that are not under your control, It's not a great design to have a  `FOREIGN KEY`.

You may use [**DEFERRABLE Clause**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180) for your constraint. This allows you to run the delete and update in a single statement before you **commit** the transaction.

```
 ALTER TABLE Projet ADD CONSTRAINT fk_succurscale foreign key(NumSuccursale)
          references Succursale(NumSuccursale) initially deferred deferrable
```

Here's an illustration of how it works.

```
declare
l_del Succursale.NumSuccursale%TYPE := 3;

l_upd_from Succursale.NumSuccursale%TYPE := 4;
l_upd_to Succursale.NumSuccursale%TYPE := 3;
BEGIN
DELETE Succursale  WHERE NumSuccursale=l_del;
UPDATE Projet   SET  NumSuccursale=NULL WHERE NumSuccursale=l_del;
COMMIT;--Constraint checking won't happen until this commit is issued.

UPDATE Succursale SET  NumSuccursale=l_upd_to WHERE NumSuccursale=l_upd_from;
UPDATE Projet SET  NumSuccursale=l_upd_to WHERE NumSuccursale=l_upd_from;
COMMIT;

END;
/
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c1ffe6e724aade35155960ed1e01bc84) of the above block.